# how to declare multidimensional array with typedef and pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, typedef

Now the question is about typedef and c styles strings.
Here is the code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define C "BTP300", "BTD310", "BTI320", "BTS330"
 typedef char* Course;// Line 1
 #define CMP(a,b,c,d) ((a[(c)])d(b[(c)]))

 int main(void) {
     Course reference, test[] = {C}; //Line 2
     sort(test,4,2);
     reference=test[0];
     difference(test, reference, 4);
     return 0;
 }


    void sort(Course a[], int n, int k) {
         int i, j;
         Course temp;
         for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
             for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                 if (CMP(a[j],a[j+1],k,>)) {
                     temp = a[j];
                     a[j] = a[j+1];
                     a[j+1] = temp;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

 void difference(Course a[], Course reference, int n) {
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
         printf("%d ", ABS(a[i] - reference));
     printf("\n");
 }
```

This is what I understood:
-Course is an alias for a pointer of char type.
-reference is a pointer of char type.

What I dont know or need to know the theory behind the code is:
1- What is test[] ??? I think its an array of pointers of type char in other words test[1] contains char*="btd310" .(I dont know the reasoning of it.)

2- how do i access the "d" in "btd310"?
3- using typedef int* how do i create a 2 dimensional int array? I was looking for something like

```
typedef int* arr;
void main(){
arr foo[]={{1,2},{3,4}}
}
```

Obviously above code didnt work for me so which way it will work i.e. i will get 2d int array.

## Thanks guys in advance. And by the way, there might be better other ways to do it but i have to learn this way.

How the two macros in above code work?

Answer (score 1):

> 1- What is test[] ??? I think its an array of pointers of type char in
>   other words test[1] contains char*="btd310" .

test is an array of type Course.

> 2- how do i access the "d" in "btd310"?

test[1][2]

> 3- using typedef int* how do i create a 2 dimensional int array?

why not just making it:

```
int foo[][2]={{1,2},{3,4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `test` is an array of `Course`, i. e. an array of `char` pointers. The type of course would be written as `char *()[]`. As to the contents of that array, the preprocessor will simply substitute `"BTP300", "BTD310", "BTI320", "BTS330"` for `C`, so the initialization of test reads `test[] = {"BTP300", "BTD310", "BTI320", "BTS330"}`.
2. You get the `'D'` with `test[1][2]`. Please note that C is case sensitive everywhere, so `'D'` is something very different than `'d'`.
3. The use of strings in the initialization of `char*` and `char ()[]` is a bit special, so better not think about that. To declare a two dimensional array of `int`, you simply use `int foo[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};` If you must use a typedef, you can use `typedef int arr[2];` to define an array type for a one dimensional array of 2 integers, and you can then make a one dimensional array of two one dimensional array of 2 integers with `arr foo[2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};`.